# Fetching table from Word document including the numbered list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Currently, I possess a code that extracts tables and paragraphs from a Word document. However, it does not encompass the numbered lists within the tables.

For example, if i have 1. Appearance in a cell, it retrieves only Appearance from it.

Can someone help me in getting the desired result 1. Appearance.

I have tried the below code for fetching the table.

```
from docx import Document
def read_information_after_keyword(docx_file_path, keyword):
doc = Document(docx_file_path)
found_keyword = False
information = {}
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        if found_keyword:
            # Assuming that the information follows the keyword in the same paragraph
            information[keyword] = paragraph.text.strip()
            break
        elif keyword in paragraph.text:
            found_keyword = True
    return information
def process_tables(docx_file_path):
doc = Document(docx_file_path)
    specification_table = None
    for table in doc.tables:
        # Extract data from each table, excluding empty rows
        table_data = []
        for row in table.rows:
            row_data = [cell.text.strip() for cell in row.cells]
            # Check if the row is not empty
            if any(row_data):
                table_data.append(row_data)
        # Check if the first row contains "Release Information"
        release_info_keyword = "Release Information"
        if release_info_keyword in table_data[0]:
            # Check if the second row contains specified keywords
            specification_header_keywords = ["Parameters", "Market", "Acceptance Criteria", "Test Methods"]
            if len(table_data) > 1 and all(keyword in table_data[1] for keyword   in specification_header_keywords):
                specification_table = table_data[1:]
                print(f"Specification Table found:")
                for row in specification_table:
                    print(row)
                print()    
    return specification_table
file_path = "D5.docx"
specification= process_tables(file_path)
```

Comment: Please attach an example document to run this code. Also please mention environment (python version) you are using to run this code.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this to extract numbered list within tables from Word**

from docx import Document

def numbrd_list(docx_file_path):

doc = Document(docx_file_path)

```
  for table in doc.tables:
    
     for row in table.rows:
        
        for cell in row.cells:
            
          for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                
              if paragraph.style.name == 'List Paragraph':
                    
                  if paragraph.text.startswith('1.'):
                        
                      list_item = paragraph.text
                      print(list_item)
```

If you want replace **list item** with

**list_item = paragraph.text.split('\n')[0]**

so it only extracts the first line of paragraph which has the numbered list